# remove all text after semi-colon using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse the below output using `awk` to remove all text after the semi-colon in each line.  Thank you :).

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR != 1 { sub(/; [^ ]*$/, "", $NF) } 1' file1.txt >: result.txt
```

**file1.txt**

```
chr1 40539722 40539865 PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1 
chr1 40542503 40542595 PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1 
chr1 40544221 40544340 PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1 
chr1 40546058 40546169 PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1;PPT1
```

**Desired result.txt**

```
chr1 40539722 40539865 PPT1
chr1 40542503 40542595 PPT1
chr1 40544221 40544340 PPT1
chr1 40546058 40546169 PPT1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with just doing

```
awk -F ';' '{ print $1 }'
```

? Seems much simpler.

Comment: Or similarly `sed s/;.*//' file1.txt >result.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You want to `cut` the file and show the first field on `;`-separated values. So what about using `cut` itself?

```
$ cut -d';' -f1 file
chr1 40539722 40539865 PPT1
chr1 40542503 40542595 PPT1
chr1 40544221 40544340 PPT1
chr1 40546058 40546169 PPT1
```

`-d` sets the delimiter and `-f` indicates which fields you want to print.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for introducing me to `cut`  :).

Comment: You are welcome ;) Note you can accept one answer but up/downvote all of them (I say this because I [see](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31678776/timeline) you accepted one and then the other, just feel free to up/downvote whatever you want).